# Why does the search term <""> return all questions?

Tags: discussion, support, search

Searching stackoverflow for the following string returns all questions.

```
<"">
```

Note that `"<>"` and `<">` or even `<''>` return nothing.

But `<"">` returns `32,093,712 results`, the same as searching `*`.

What is the relevance of having a pair of double quotes inside a pair of angle brackets?

Apologies if meta is not the right place for this.

Comment: What was the intended result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems that [`<something>`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3Csomething%3E) returns the same search results as [`something`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=something). The angle brackets seems to be ignored, maybe to prevent [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) or other hacking tricks. So it is no surprise that when [`""`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%22) returns all questions, [`<"">`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3C%22%22%3E) does as well. Remember that the double quotes are used to search for an exact match when multiple terms are involved, but if there's nothing inside the quotes, everything is a match.