# Are there any undocumented options for doing searches?

Tags: support, search

I noticed in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284106/why-does-the-search-term-return-all-questions) it mentions using the asterisk in doing wildcard searches, but I couldn't find it in the help pages.  Are there other search options that aren't documented?

Comment: The asterisk is documented on the search help page https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Comment: I remember `code:"keywords here"` for code search being undocumented.

Comment: @user289905 [code is documented](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: @RobertLongson Ah, but it wasn’t before [May 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20200420133834/https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)! And it was documented as undocumented here: [Does the SO search engine require escape characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153439/289905).

Comment: Related: *[What are the hidden features of Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211)*. 53 answers. It is worth browsing in any case - not only for this specific question.

Comment: One of them is *[Wildcards in tag filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-are-the-hidden-features-of-stack-exchange/92308#92308)*

Comment: There some real gems in there. E.g., *"[Putting a parameter `?lastactivity` at the end of the question's URL will redirect you to the last activated (modified) post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-are-the-hidden-features-of-stack-exchange/199300#199300)"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use of the asterisk `*` in searches is the last item of the first bullet list in the ["Search help"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) page.

> If you need to refine and narrow your search, here are some basic tips:
>
> - (...)
> - Use wildcard searches to broaden results; add an asterisk (*) anywhere in the word, like encour* or Ex*nge.